# How to find which trigger actually started the Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have multiple vue projects inside a repository which are nested in a folder. In my Azure pipeline I want to find which folder actually was updated and only build and deploy that folder. How can I find which trigger among all my triggers actually started the pipeline?

```
pipeline.yml: 

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - prj/appB/*
    - prj/appA/*

...
```

I have tried some of the variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), such as Build.SourceBranch but it doesn't have any information about appB or appA folder that I could possibly use.

Answer (score 3):

I came across [this](https://pumpingco.de/blog/run-an-azure-pipelines-job-only-if-source-code-has-changed/) post which outlines how to add some scripts to identify the changes. So far that is my solution to comparing the changes with folders I need and customize the rest of the pipelines based on that.

```
Snippet is taken from the blog posted by [ROBIN-MANUEL THIEL][1]
#!/bin/sh
PATH_FILTER="src/"
CHANGED_FILES=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
MATCH_COUNT=0

echo "Checking for file changes..."
for FILE in $CHANGED_FILES
do
  if [[ $FILE == *$PATH_FILTER* ]]; then
    echo "MATCH:  ${FILE} changed"
    MATCH_FOUND=true
    MATCH_COUNT=$(($MATCH_COUNT+1))
  else
    echo "IGNORE: ${FILE} changed"
  fi
done

echo "$MATCH_COUNT match(es) for filter '$PATH_FILTER' found."
if [[ $MATCH_COUNT -gt 0 ]]; then
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SOURCE_CODE_CHANGED;isOutput=true]true"
else
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SOURCE_CODE_CHANGED;isOutput=true]false"
fi
```

The snippet above will fetch all the changes from the last time the pipeline has run & check them against the PATH_FILTER , from there you can customize your pipeline. Full description is in the block post linked above.

Comment: I'm waiting to see if someone else has a better answer, since this is more a work around and not really the answer I was hoping. I'll wait a bit an then accept this if I no one else comments : )

Comment: You may check `git diff-tree` command to see whether it can achieve your requirement. Check my following reply.

Answer (score 1):

You may check `git diff-tree` command to see whether it can achieve your requirement. This command can get the changed files:

```
steps:

- powershell: |
    $a = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion)  
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fileName]$a" 

- powershell: |
    echo "$env:fileName"
```

Comment: Hi Cece, it appears this is still in the lines of what I reply above. I am hoping Azure has it's own way of doing this but more and more I'm thinking it doesn't and git compares is the only way. It would be nice to have a simple way of distinguishing what triggered in the yaml file using part of their SDK

Comment: I'd like to suggest you submit a suggestion at website https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21.